# HEVC captures the bits of transform coefficients

Tags: decoder, hevc, video-codecs, h.265

How can I modify the code so that when decoding an h265 video stream using HM, it captures the number of bits occupied by the transform coefficients of each CTU in the bitstream?

I found that the transform coefficients are decoded in the parseCoeffNxN function in xDecodeTransform. So I added a variable in parseCoeffNxN to record the number of times decodeBin is called, trying to record the number of decoded bits. But the number differs a lot from what I see in HEVCanalyzer.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/keEz3.png)

Comment: I just wanna know the size (in bits) of the transform coefficients for each CTU after entropy coding

Answer (score 1):

There must be better solutions, but what I once did was to modify the parsing stage at the CTU-level (iirc) of HM, so I could figure out how many bits have been fed to the CABAC decoder since the last flush. It sounds complicated, but it's doable.

Comment: thanks a lot, could you tell me more detail about the way to record the bits which have been fed to the CABAC decoder. Is it possible to distinguish between them the proportion of transformations and predictions? Now I'm temporarily using HEVC analyser to log the bits